# Generate nested constant structs in C at compile time

Tags: arrays, c, struct

I'm trying to generate a large constant lookup table at compile time in C (C99), and each entry to the lookup table has a pointer to another const program struct . this isn't possible because undeclared here can't be completion

how two edit this code to can be compilation is run ?

```
typedef struct  menueItem_t {
    const struct menueItem_t *menuNext;
    const struct menueItem_t *menuParent;
    const struct menueItem_t *menuChild;
    const struct menueItem_t *menuPre;
    const pFuncPara_t menuCallback;
    const char *menuLable;
} menueItem_t;


//the declaration 
const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};


const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"}; 
const menueItem_t  NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

the error view
[image]

Comment: This seems to be nearly the same as [your closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72186642/10622916). Please, either improve the other question or explain what's the difference between the two questions. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the output/error message *as text* and format it as a code block.

Comment: I improved the other first question  and there is no difference between them  , This is better for simplicity

Comment: Show the error message **as text** in your question and make sure your code does not contain unrelated errors. I get more errors compared to your screenshot.

Comment: The error messages are plain and clear, for example: Where you reference `Test2`, it is not known yet. Does it help to declare it before?

Comment: Either forward declarations as `extern`, or forward declarations as *tentative* definitions (i.e. with no initializer) should help.

Comment: There is probably not much point declaring the `menuCallback` member `const` because none of the other members are declared `const`.

Answer (score 2):

Adding forward declarations for the items you declare should fix the problem:

```
//forward declaration 
extern const menueItem_t Settings;
extern const menueItem_t Exit;
extern const menueItem_t Test;
 
extern const menueItem_t Test1;
extern const menueItem_t Test2;
extern const menueItem_t Test3; 
extern const menueItem_t  NullItem;

// the declaration
...
```

In situations when no circular references exist you can re-order the declarations to eliminate forward reference. For example, moving `NullItem` to the top of the declaration list would let your code compile without forward-declaring `NullItem`.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ian Abbott remarks either forward definition with `extern` or tentative definition (dropping the `extern`) works, see the code below. There was a `NULL` too many in the `NullItem`'s initialization, a struct definition was missing and the function pointer for the callback function needed some care.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct pFuncPara_t {
    int status;
    char* pDescription;
} pFuncPara_t;

typedef struct  menueItem_t {
    const struct menueItem_t *menuNext;
    const struct menueItem_t *menuParent;
    const struct menueItem_t *menuChild;
    const struct menueItem_t *menuPrevious;
    const pFuncPara_t (*menuCallback)(pFuncPara_t in);
    const char *menuLabel;
} menueItem_t;


const pFuncPara_t menuDummy(pFuncPara_t in){ return in; }
const pFuncPara_t menuExit(pFuncPara_t in) { return in; }

extern const menueItem_t  NullItem;
extern const menueItem_t Test1;
extern const menueItem_t Test2;
extern const menueItem_t Test3;
extern const menueItem_t Settings;
extern const menueItem_t Exit;
extern const menueItem_t Test;

//the declaration 
const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};


const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"}; 
const menueItem_t  NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};


int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing the original code would have declared `pFuncPara_t` as a pointer to some function type, which seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the variables as `extern` before you reference them will work in this case:

```
// forward declarations
extern const menueItem_t Settings;
extern const menueItem_t Exit;
extern const menueItem_t Test;
extern const menueItem_t Test1;
extern const menueItem_t Test2;
extern const menueItem_t Test3;
extern const menueItem_t NullItem;

//the declaration 
const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};
const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"}; 
const menueItem_t NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

That will not work if the full definitions of the variables are `static`:

```
// forward declarations
extern const menueItem_t Settings;
extern const menueItem_t Exit;
extern const menueItem_t Test;
extern const menueItem_t Test1;
extern const menueItem_t Test2;
extern const menueItem_t Test3;
extern const menueItem_t NullItem;

//the declaration 
static const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
static const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
static const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};
static const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
static const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
static const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"}; 
static const menueItem_t NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

The above code will result in errors about static declarations following non-static declarations.

An alternative to declaring the variables as `extern` in the forward declarations is to declare them as "tentative" definitions by omitting their initializer:

```
// forward declarations
const menueItem_t Settings;
const menueItem_t Exit;
const menueItem_t Test;
const menueItem_t Test1;
const menueItem_t Test2;
const menueItem_t Test3;
const menueItem_t NullItem;

//the declaration 
const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};
const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"}; 
const menueItem_t NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

That has the advantage that it can be made to work when the full definitions of the variables are `static` by also making the forward declarations `static`:

```
// forward declarations
static const menueItem_t Settings;
static const menueItem_t Exit;
static const menueItem_t Test;
static const menueItem_t Test1;
static const menueItem_t Test2;
static const menueItem_t Test3;
static const menueItem_t NullItem;

//the declaration 
static const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
static const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
static const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};
static const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
static const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
static const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"}; 
static const menueItem_t NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
```

Since the initialization of `NullItem` does not refer to any other menu items, it does not really need a forward declaration. Moving its full declaration before the other variables would suffice:

```
// forward declarations
const menueItem_t Settings;
const menueItem_t Exit;
const menueItem_t Test;
const menueItem_t Test1;
const menueItem_t Test2;
const menueItem_t Test3;

//the declaration 
const menueItem_t NullItem  = {NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL};
const menueItem_t Settings  = {&Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuDummy, "S"};
const menueItem_t Exit  = {&NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, &NullItem, menuExit, "E"};
const menueItem_t Test  = {&Exit, &Settings, &NullItem, &Test1, menuDummy, "T"};
const menueItem_t Test1  = {&Test2, &NullItem, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T1"};
const menueItem_t Test2  = {&Test3, &Test1, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T2"};
const menueItem_t Test3  = {&NullItem, &Test2, &Test, &NullItem, menuDummy, "T3"};
```